# SQL MODIFY COLUMN PRECISION SIZE

Tags: plsql

I have more than 1200 columns in number data_type with variable size:

```
TABLE_NAME.DATA_TYPE(NUMBER(10,2)
```

In a single shot I want to change all those column sizes into another size like:

```
TABLE_NAME.DATA_TYPE(NUMBER(15,2)
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Please try to explain your question a bit..

Comment: I have more than 1200 columns in number data_type with variable size.
 now i want to change all those column size into another size  like number(15,2)

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is you can't. You have to do them one at a time.... but you can basically use some other code to do it all in one shot for you. You can use a loop to send a query to your db using all the columns names which you can export.

If you need to get all your column names from a table you can do this by querying the [Information Schema views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933204%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

```
SELECT *
FROM DB_NAME.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Customers'
```

Then export those columns and place them either in an array or in another temp table. Then create a loop that cycles through all those column name and sends a query to change the data type and....BAM all at once.

Hope this helps

---

Answer (score 0):

```html
declare @schema nvarchar(255)
declare @table nvarchar(255)='TABLE_NAME'
declare @col nvarchar(255)
declare @dtype nvarchar(255)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare maxcols cursor for

select
    c.TABLE_SCHEMA,
    c.TABLE_NAME,
    c.COLUMN_NAME,
    c.DATA_TYPE
from
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t on
    c.TABLE_CATALOG = t.TABLE_CATALOG
    and c.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA
    and c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
    and t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
where
    c.DATA_TYPE like 'NUMBER(10,2)'
    and c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1

open maxcols

fetch next from maxcols into @schema, @table, @col, @dtype

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    set @sql = 'alter table [' + @schema + '].[' + @table + 
        '] alter column [' + @col + '] ' + @dtype + 'NUMBER(15,2)'
    exec sp_executesql @sql

    fetch next from maxcols into @schema, @table, @col, @dtype
end

close maxcols
deallocate maxcols
```